# Adding additional references automatically

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, lib

I have alot of lib files in a folder and I want them to be additional references in the linker. Do I have to type them all in manually or is there a way to do that automatically? I use Visual Studio 2017

Comment: For visual studio in particular, linking is usually a somewhat careful affair.  There are 4 distinct run-times (static vs. dll) x (release, debug) that you have to choose between, and the one you pick has to be the same for all libs you include (hence most libs for windows ship 4 copies--one compiled for each mode).  So it might be worth looking through the pile of libs you have to determine if you need to prune some out.

Comment: Did you try `yourdir/*.lib`?

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't particularly clear but if the files are source files and if using the IDE for project management you can right click on the project in solution explorer and under the add menu select add existing files. The dialog that comes up allows you to select multiple files just like any other windows list view (clicking the mouse while while holding the shift key to select a range and while holding alt to toggle individual files).

If you mean some other type of 'reference' you need to specify what you mean.